# Renombrar miles de archivos a la vez con un patrón específico

Tags: windows, bash

Como se ve en la foto:

[image: (introducir la descripción del enlace aquí)]

Tengo miles y miles de archivos que tienen el formato: nombre - 10números, por ejemplo `zapateria-1092328745` o `1-2-1923412345`. Siempre es el nombre del archivo más 10 números aparte, ¿habría alguna forma para quitarle esos 10 números a todos los archivos a la vez?

Muchísimas gracias.

Comment: Hola dev. Y si tienes dos archivos `zapateria-1092328745` y `zapateria-1092328746` y le quitas los números, ¿cómo identificas a `zapateria` de `zapateria`?

Comment: son los mismos, osea si se renombraran quedarian como zapateria y zapateria (1) supongo, pero me da igual si este segundo se borra puesto que son los mismos

Comment: Buenas tardes, deberias reformular la pregunta y especificar sistema operativo, que estás intentando, etc. Nuestra comunidad no resuelve un problema a partir de una idea. Saludos

Comment: Hola Santi92, lo estoy haciendo en windows y llevo toda la noche buscando y he visto que con bash es posible pero no consigo lograrlo

Comment: Ahora, por favor, sigue [esta guía](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) y coloca un ejemplo completo, mínimo y verificable de lo que estas haciendo para que la ayuda pueda fluir. Si no tienes idea, empieza con esto: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6845194/783618 y luego con esto otro: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/12904

Comment: Si es que el patrón de los nombres es:  textos-10Numeros.formato, lo que se me ocurre es que almacenes en una variable todos tus files y cuentes desde el final hacia el inicio 10 caracteres. Luego uses todo el dato restante para generar un nuevo nombre. no se si me dejo entender.

Comment: Toledano no entiendo absolutamente nada del enlace que me enviaste :S, no se inglés y tampoco entiendo esos códigos que salen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una posible solución en bash es:

```
$ touch {for,bar,baz}-1234567890.jpg
$ ls -ltr *.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 guest 1049089 0 Sep 11 20:01 for-1234567890.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 guest 1049089 0 Sep 11 20:01 bar-1234567890.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 guest 1049089 0 Sep 11 20:01 baz-1234567890.jpg
$ for file in *.jpg; do mv $file $(echo $file | sed -e 's/[0-9]\{10\}.jpg$/.jpg/' ) ;done
$ ls -ltr *.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 guest 1049089 0 Sep 11 20:01 for-.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 guest 1049089 0 Sep 11 20:01 bar-.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 guest 1049089 0 Sep 11 20:01 baz-.jpg
```

**IMPORTANTE** Si hay colisión de nombres sin los números dejará sólo uno de los archivos. Usar con cuidado.

Una opción segura es utilizar la opción `--backup=TYPE` del comando `mv`. Donde `TYPE` es uno de los siguientes.

- none, off nunca hace backup (aún cuando se ha dado la opción --backup)
- numbered, t     hace backups numéricos
- existing, nil   numérico si el backup existe, si no simple
- simple, never   siempre hacer backup simple

La opción backup agrega un sufijo al archivo en caso de existir.

Con esta opción, por ejemplo, `zapateria.jpg` pasa a `zapateria.jpg~` ó `zapateria.jpg~1~`.

Esto evitará al menos perder archivos repetidos, si son muchos, debería revevaluarse la forma de renombrar los archivos en masa.

Ejemplo con numbered backup:

for file in *.jpg; do mv --backup=numbered $file $(echo $file | sed -e 's/[0-9]{10}.jpg$/.jpg/' ) ;done

Si quisieras remover también guión medio que separa el nombre del número, simplemente cambia:

`'s/[0-9]\{10\}.jpg$/.jpg/'` por `'s/-[0-9]\{10\}.jpg$/.jpg/'`.

Referencias en inglés:

- [Serverfault - How do I rename multiple files by removing characters in bash?](https://serverfault.com/questions/345095/how-do-i-rename-multiple-files-by-removing-characters-in-bash). Respuesta de [James O'Gorman](https://serverfault.com/users/90132/james-ogorman)
- [sed Manual - Regular Expressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html)

Puede resultar útil este [tutorial](http://vensign.com/como-utilizar-el-comando-sed-en-la-vida-real-ejemplos-y-tips-parte-1/) del comando sed.

**ACTUALIZACION**

Si estás en ambiente Windows y deseas usar bash, las opciones que conozco y he usado en algún momento son:

- [git for Windows](https://git-scm.com/downloads) que incluye MinGW (es lo que usé para la demo).
- [Minimalist GNU for Windows
  (MinGW)](http://www.mingw.org/)
- [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/)

Comment: Me parece que no aplica porque esta utilizando Windows,

Comment: Asumí un correcto etiquetado de la pregunta (dice `bash`) tal vez mala mía. Por eso actualicé e indiqué, si quiere usar `bash` en Windows para lo que quiere resolver (bien por él), le doy opciones.

Comment: hola Asiduo, estoy intentando usar bash en windows para utilizar el ejemplo que me pusiste, muchas gracias por tu ayuda, a ver si lo consigo (me equivoque, no era bash, es bat)

Comment: @dev importante, acá lo que indica Toledano de las colisiones es importante. Con `mv` los archivos se pisan.

Comment: entonces el ejemplo no servira?

Comment: Nuevamente, si tienes `zapateria-1092328745.jpg` y `zapateria-1092328746.jpg`, ¿quieres las dos?

Comment: Te agregué la opción de usar `--backup` con el comando `mv`. Por las dudas.

Comment: ya lo he conseguido, muchas gracias!

Comment: Me alegro mucho haber podido ser de ayuda!

Answer (score 0):

Acabo de escribir un pequeño script PERO EN EL LENGUAJE R (https://www.r-project.org/).

```
#borre las primeras lineas pues no es necesario. solo lo use para generar los nombres.
setwd("/home/luis/Code/R/Imagenes/")
dir()

lista <- list.files(pattern = "*.jpg")

caracteres <- nchar(lista) - 15
#15 = 3 de formato, 1 del punto, 10 de los numeros, 1 del gion

nom <- substr(lista,1,caracteres)

nombre <- paste0(nom,".jpg")


file.rename(lista,nombre)
```

En cuanto al proceso de la ejecución posiblemente no estés familiarizado con el lenguaje así me que anime a grabar un pequeño video, en el que explico cómo ejecutarlo. Ojo que para ello tienes que tener instalado R (que es muy simple) al igual que el RStudio (https://www.rstudio.com/).

aca el link del video: https://www.dropbox.com/s/p9mmny6d0qxhfxr/rename_file.mp4?dl=0

PD: Si trabajas con Rstudio puedes usar las teclas control+shift+h para reemplazar la línea que inicia con setwd().